# C# - Error while copying content to a stream - (Async HTTP Request)

Tags: c#, .net

The method *queryUrl* takes a list of URLs as an input and is making parallel queries on these URLs. After receiving the HTML responses, the method is putting each response in a List and is returning the List. But calling the method *queryUrl* in the main Method is causing for some URL the following error: *Error while copying content to a stream*

The method seems to work for some URL but does not seem to work for other URL (->I am getting the error message after 10 minutes). Unfortunately I do not know for which URL it doesn`t work.

```
internal static async Task<List<string>> queryUrl(List<string> urls)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();

    var requests = urls.ToArray().Select
        (
            url => client.GetAsync(url)
        ).ToList();

    await Task.WhenAll(requests);

    var responses = requests.Select
        (
            task => task.Result
        );

    List<string> responseList = new List<string>();
    foreach (var r in responses)
    {
        var response = await r.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        responseList.Add(response);
    }

    return responseList;
}
```

The method is called in the main method by:

```
List<string> html = await queryUrl(urls);
```

Comment: None of the answers was helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
await Task.WhenAll(requests);
var responses = requests.Select(
    task = > task.Result
);
```

try below code:

```
var responses = await Task.WhenAll(requests);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that response could be in Unsucessful state. Try to add r.IsSuccessStatusCode check:

```
    foreach (var r in responses)
    {
        if(r.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var response = await r.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            responseList.Add(response);
        }
    }
```